# Linq query that involves doing group by with two tables that are not directly connected

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

In a EF model with these classes:

```
 class BoxOutput
 {
     public long BoxId { get; set; }
     public virtual Box Box { get; set; }
     public long BoxId { get; set; }
     public long CategoryId { get; set; }
     public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
     public long? ColorId { get; set; }
     public virtual Category Color { get; set; }
     public decimal Weight { get; set; }

     // ...and other irrelevant properties
 }

 class BoxInput
 {
     public long BoxId { get; set; }
     public virtual Box Box { get; set; }
     public long BoxId { get; set; }
     public long CategoryId { get; set; }
     public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
     public long? ColorId { get; set; }
     public virtual Category Color { get; set; }
     public decimal Weight { get; set; }

     // ...and other irrelevant properties
 }
```

...how can I do a LINQ query that, for a specific box (eg. `boxId = 12`), returns this?:

```
  category.name    color.name      inputWeightsSum      outputWeightsSum
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     c             null               0                    0
     c             red                0                    0
     c             blue               0                    0
     m             null               0                    0
     m             red                0                    0
     m             blue               0                    0
                           ....
```

I'm currently almost achieving this but the "optional color" is giving me troubles when doing the "cartesian product": I'm not showing nulls...

This is what I have.

```
var boxesInputs = dbContext.BoxesInputs
.Where(c => c.BoxId == 12)
.GroupBy(c => new { c.CategoryId, c.ColorId })
.Select(g => new
{
    categoryId = g.Key.CategoryId,
    colorId = g.Key.ColorId,
    sumOfWeights = g.Sum(r => (decimal?)r.Weight) ?? 0,
}).ToList();

var boxesOutputs = dbContext.BoxesOutputs
.Where(c => c.BoxId == 12)
.GroupBy(c => new { c.CategoryId, c.ColorId })
.Select(g => new
{
    categoryId = g.Key.CategoryId,
    colorId = g.Key.ColorId,
    sumOfWeights = g.Sum(r => (decimal?)r.Weight) ?? 0,
}).ToList();

var categoriesAndColors = dbContext.Categories.AsEnumerable()
.SelectMany(category => dbContext.Colors.AsEnumerable()
.Select(color => new
{
    category = new
    {
        categoryId = category.CategoryId,
        name = category.Name,
    },
    color = new
    {
        colorId = color.ColorId,
        name = color.Name,
    },
    inputWeightsSum = boxesInputs.Where(r => r.categoryId == category.CategoryId && r.colorId == color.ColorId).Sum(r => (decimal?) r.sumOfWeights) ?? 0,
    outputWeightsSum = boxesOutputs.Where(r => r.categoryId == category.CategoryId && r.colorId == color.ColorId).Sum(r => (decimal?)r.sumOfWeights) ?? 0,
})).ToList();
```

In the previous code, the first two queries return this:

```
  category.name    color.name      inputWeightsSum
 -------------------------------------------------------
     c             null               0
     c             red                0
     c             blue               0
     m             null               0
     m             red                0
     m             blue               0 
                           ....

  category.name    color.name      outputWeightsSum
 -------------------------------------------------------
     c             null               0
     c             red                0
     c             blue               0
     m             null               0
     m             red                0
     m             blue               0 
                           ....
```

And the third one joins these two. I guess I need to improve that join because I'm losing the nulls.

Also this code uses in-memory code and I would like it to be a one-sql-query (linq-to-entities and not linq-to-objects mixed with linq-to-entities). Is it possible? giving that BoxOutput and BoxInput are two different tables and they are not directly connected. Or I will end up with 3 queries at the end no matter what?

Comment: I think I need a GroupJoin

Comment: Are you just trying to get a cartesian product?

Comment: The first two queries of my code are granted to be correct.. I just want to merge those two into one result, grouping by "(category, color)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select an identical anonymous type from both tables, union them together, then do your group and select. Something like this:

```
dbContext.BoxesInputs
.Select(g => new TempClass
{
    CategoryId = g.CategoryId,
    ColorId = g.ColorId,
    InputWeight = r.Weight,
    OutputWeight = 0,
})
.Union(dbContext.BoxesOutputs
    .Select(g => new TempClass
    {
        CategoryId = g.CategoryId,
        ColorId = g.ColorId,
        InputWeight = 0,
        OutputWeight = r.Weight
    })
)
.GroupBy(c => new { c.CategoryId, c.ColorId })
.Select(g => new
{
    categoryId = g.Key.CategoryId,
    colorId = g.Key.ColorId,
    sumOfInputWeights = g.Sum(r => r.InputWeight),
    sumOfOutputWeights = g.Sum(r => r.OutputWeight),
}).ToList();

public class TempClass
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int ColorID { get; set; }
    public decimal InnerWeight { get; set; }
    public decimal OuterWeight { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But then I would be getting only one column "sumOfWeights" and I need the "inputsSumOfWeights" and "outputsSumOfWeights", separetly within the same result

Comment: check my edit. That should work. Not sure if optimal, but better than pulling the whole table into memory probably.

Comment: But I think that it will not be able to transform to SQL with the Union having an argument that is other table?

Comment: thats exactly what union is intended to do. there is a `UNION` in SQL too. depends on your LINQ setup though. No better way to know than to try. My syntax might not be correct with `Union`, I do not use it often. MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358407(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'm not sure that I can use union over a list of anonymous? `Error: 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>' does not contain a definition for 'Union'...`

Comment: store it in a temp class like i did in my update and it will work. i mistakenly thought the anonymous types would be recognized as identical